# Should I list notable clients on the back of my business card as a freelancer?

Tags: business-cards

I'm redesigning my business cards, and since my last design, I've spearheaded a few projects for some high profile clients (in their respective regions).
Is it a good idea to add their logo to the back of my card titled 'clients?'

Comment: If you have a falling out with a client you'll need to print new business cards.

Comment: Definitely ask your clients if they're okay with you making that implied endorsement on their behalf.

Comment: Just a put a link to your personal website where you go into detail about the projects.  The logo by itself means nothing.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you have specifically asked for permission, you should not for two reasons:

1. Having their logo on your business card says nothing about the works you did and provides limited value to new clients. It may give the false impression that they are endorsing your skills and work
2. Most companies have trademarked or copyrighted their logos, so without their permission you are not allowed to use the logos.  Any company large enough to be worth having on your card probably does not want random people advertising the relationship.

Comment: I know some motivational speakers that do have the logo of the companies on their personal webpage. I think it is possible to reach an arrangement with the company you worked with.
However, on the business card, I would say it is too much.

Comment: Having permission certainly changes the scenario, but I'd still say no based on 1

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely not. If need be you could hand write contacts on the back of the card.

In general the notion is that you could supply references on request. You'd have to be able to supply a real contact in whatever company, not just the company name. Depending of what you did and what job you are applying for you might need to annotate your reference list for the particular situation.